# Prints only "An error occurred in the program!"

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int age;
    char gender;
    printf("Are you male or female (m/f)?");
    scanf("%c",&gender);
    printf("Enter your age:");
    scanf("%d",&age);
    printf("\n");

    if(gender=="m"){
        if(age>=0 && age<=55){
         printf("You are a man in your best years!\n");
        }
        else if (age>=56 && age<=100){
            printf("You are a wise man!\n");}
        else{
    printf("An error occurred in the program!");}
    }
    else if(gender=="f"){
    if(age>=0 && age<=55){
         printf("You are a beauty!\n");
        }
        else if (age>=56 && age<=100){
            printf("You look young for your age!\n");}
        else{
    printf("An error occurred in the program!");}

    }
    else{
    printf("An error occurred in the program!");}
    return 0;
}
```

The program is not working correctly. It prints only the last else statements print i.e. "An error occurred in the program!". I also tried to put the all the conditions in the same small brackets

like:

```
if(gender=="f"&& age>=0 && age<=55))
```

but still it didn't output the expected result.

Comment: `gender=="m"` --> `gender=='m'`

Comment: By analogy, the same would apply to `else if(gender=="f")`

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing a `char` to a `string` literal `(gender == "m")`. Double quotes are for string. Use single quotes around m `(gender == 'm')` and f `(gender == 'f')`.